Dutch Public Transportation Electronic Payment Options
An unplanned trip to Amsterdam has me without my usual stash of Euros and electronic public transportation card.  I would like to use the Train / Bus system for transportation to a relative in Amsterdam.
Can I use my iPhone / Applepay or some other form of electronic payment?  If it helps, I am a Floridian / USAmerican.

There are ticket machine anywhere (also very conveniently located at airport, but a bit busier, at least the nearest ones from exit). You can pay with credit-cards or debit-cards. I never used other options (some cities allow applepay, and many have an app where you can buy tickets directly on the app). I do not know Amsterdam (city) (I just I do not think the trains to main station allow it). -- so I let locals to answer precisely. but be reassured: cards can be used nearly everywhere also for tickets

@GiacomoCatenazzi, the current public transport payment system does allow card use directly as well as payment systems on phones, without the extra money charged on paper tickets.

Relevant: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/180515/2708

Since the OVpay system was rolled out over the last year or so, you can use any contactless payment card (or something that works like one, such as various mobile payment systems) to check in and out just like you would do with an anonymous OV-chipkaart.
This system is entirely equivalent to an anonymous OV-chip in coverage (so you can use it for buses, trams, trains, etc., but not to rent an OV-fiets bike). There's certainly no need to queue at ticket machines or pay the 7.5€ for an anonymous OV-chip and worry about keeping your balance topped up.
For completeness, this is what OVpay lists as the supported payment methods:

You can check in and out with:

contactless debits card from ABN AMRO, ASN bank, bunq, ING, Rabobank, Knab, Regiobank, SNS or Triodos
contactless credit cards from Mastercard and Visa (issued by ICS)
smartphones that are set up with contactless payment with a card from above-mentioned debit and credit cards. Also with Apple Pay and Google Wallet
a foreign contactless debit or credit cards [sic] from Maestro, V pay, Mastercard or Visa

You won't even need an OV-chipkaart or subscription. No registration is necessary.


Is this as simple as summoning ApplePay (double-click right button) and hold the iPhone up to the OV reader?

@gatorback I guess so. I've never had an Apple phone, but from what I see from fellow passengers, it must be something like that. With a physical (plastic) card, it's literally just holding the card against the reader for a few seconds, and on Android it's just waking up your phone and holding it against the reader.

@gatorback In the Walls & Apple Pay settings, under Travel Cards / Express Travel Card, select a card. If the Dutch system supports it then you actually don't have to do anything other than touch the reader with your phone: it will wake up the phone and use that card without even requiring Face ID.

Just make sure you do not have a bought tickets and a payment system for OVPay on the same phone or a payment card with your phone.

yes it works just by holding your phone to the reader, do not forget to both check-in and check-out, else if you do not check-out you get charged the maximum fare for a single trip and not the distance-based fare.

The last time I was in Amsterdam (May 2024), I used Apple Pay, but the express travel card option didn’t work so I had to double click to activate Apple Pay. (Unlike say in London, where the express travel card option does work.)

Just received confirmation from OVPay that Apple Pay’s Express Mode is not supported, so you’ll have to use Face ID (or Touch ID or passcode) to use it, like for any payment.
